# How to get 2 selected drop-down option in one tag in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-multiselect

Please help me with this.I'm stuck from an hours. I have 2 fields 1st one is language drop-down and 2nd one is language level. When I select one of the Language and one of the language level. Then after clicking on add button..how Can I display these 2 selected option in one tag? [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmRwQ.png)
Using Vue-multi select

```js
<script>
import VueMultiselect from 'vue-multiselect'
export default {
  components: { VueMultiselect },
  data () {
    return {
      languages:[],
      selectedLanguage:[],
      languageLevels:[],
      selectedLanguageLevel:[],
      showLang: false,
    }
  },
  computed: {
    langLevel: function(){
      return this.selectedLanguage + ' - ' + this.selectedLanguageLevel 
    }
  },

  methods:{
    getLang() {
      this.showLang = true
    },

    addLanguage (newLanguage) {
      const tagLanguage = {
        language: newLanguage,
        // code: newLanguage.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000000))
      }
      this.languages.push(tagLanguage)
      this.selectedLanguage.push(tagLanguage)
    },
    getLanguage: function () {
      this.axios
        .get(this.baseURL + "language", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.languages = response.data.data;
          console.warn(response.data.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    },
    getLanguageLevel: function () {
      this.axios
        .get(this.baseURL + "language-level", {
          headers: {
            Authorization: "Bearer " + this.token,
          },
        })
        .then((response) => {
          this.languageLevels = response.data.data;
          console.warn(response.data.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {});
    },
  },
  beforeMount() {  
    this.getLanguage();
    this.getLanguageLevel();
    this.token = "token updated";
    console.warn(this.token);
    
  },
}
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<template>

  <div class = "pl-20">
                <div class="flex">
                <label class = 'inline-block w-32 text-base text-gray2 font-normal mr-11 self-center' for="language">Language</label>
                <VueMultiselect class="w-44 mr-7 my-2.5" v-model="selectedLanguage" tag-placeholder="Add this as new language" placeholder="Search language" label="language" track-by="id" :options="languages" :multiple="true" :taggable="true" @tag="addLanguage">
                </VueMultiselect>

                <VueMultiselect class="w-44 my-2.5" v-model="selectedLanguageLevel" :options="languageLevels" placeholder="Select Level" track-by="id" label="language_level">
                </VueMultiselect>
                </div>
 
                <div class="ml-48 ">
                  <span class="text-sm mr-2.5">And</span>
                    <button class="bg-btnBgGray mr-2.5 px-1 py-0.5 rounded text-xs">Below</button>
                    <button class="bg-btnBgGray mr-2.5 px-1 py-0.5 rounded text-xs">Above</button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="ml-44 mt-2">
                    <button class="bg-gray3 text-white px-7 py-1 rounded-3xl" @click="getLang">Add</button>
                    </div>
                  <!-- <input type="text" class="border-textGray my-2.5 ml-52 pl-5 w-96 h-9 rounded-md" id="language" placeholder=""> -->
                  <div class="border border-black my-2.5 ml-44 pl-5 pt-1.5 w-96 h-9 rounded-md self-center" v-if="showLang">{{ langLevel }}</div>
                </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `computed` property:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data() {
    return {
      selected: '',
      options: [
        { text: 'English' },
        { text: 'Italian' },
        { text: 'Spanish' }
      ],
      level: '',
      levels: [
        { text: 'One' },
        { text: 'Two' },
        { text: 'Three' }
      ],
      showLang: false,
      tags: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getLang() {
      if (this.selected === '' || this.level === '') return
      let obj = {lang: this.selected, lvl: this.level }
      if(!this.containsObject(obj, this.tags)) this.tags.push(obj)
      this.showLang = true
      this.selected = ''
      this.level = ''
    },
    removeTag(i) {
      this.tags.splice(i, 1)
    },
    containsObject(obj, list) {
      for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        if (list[i].lang === obj.lang && list[i].lvl === obj.lvl ) {
          return true;
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.tags {
  border-radius: .5em;
  background: #bdbdbd;
  display: inline;
  padding: .2em;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: .8em;
}
li {
  margin: .2em;
}
.sel {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  gap: .5em;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-radius: .5em;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
button {
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: transparent;
  background: #4a4a4a;
  padding: .5em 1.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  margin: .5em 0;
}
h3 {
  margin: 0;
}
select {
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: .5em;
  width: 10em;
}
#demo {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.lang {
  justify-self: center;
  width: 17em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <h3>Language</h3>
  <div class="lang">
    <div class="sel">
       <select v-model="selected">
         <option disabled value="">Language</option>
         <option v-for="option in options" :value="option.text">
           {{ option.text }}
         </option>
       </select>
       <select v-model="level">
         <option disabled value="">Level</option>
         <option v-for="option in levels" :value="option.text">
           {{ option.text }}
         </option>
       </select>
    </div>
    <button @click="getLang">Add</button>
    <ul>
      <li class="list" v-for="(tag, i) in tags" :key="i">
        <div class="tags" @click="removeTag(i)">{{ tag.lang }} {{ tag.lvl }}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But there is no tag option...I want taggable selection

Comment: Try now, I updated answer

Comment: Have you saw my updated question. I added one image, there is some condition. In your solution, I'm able to select same lang and level multiple time. And In tagged option I'm not able to remove previous tagged language and level. Can you please help me. Please see the attach image...Thank you for your previous reply